# robotframework open browser in remote server not work from web page

Tags: selenium, firefox, robotframework, selenium2library

I've this use case:
- robot and application server(apache+php) installed in a linux remote server
- a web page that call robot file.

My robot file (demo.robot):

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Google search
        Set Environment Variable        webdriver.gecko.driver  /home/user/robot/geckodriver
         Set Environment Variable       webdriver.firefox.bin   /home/user/robot/firefox/firefox
        Open Browser    https://www.google.it   firefox
```

My php file:

```
<?php
$fff =shell_exec ('export DISPLAY=192.168.178.22:0.0 && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/python-3.8.0/lib && export PATH=/usr/python-3.8.0/bin:/home/user/robot/geckodriver:/home/user/robot/firefox:/usr/bin/geckodriver:$PATH && cd /usr/www/httpd/htdocs/enm/ && robot ./demo/demoSuite.robot');
    $var =  "Esecuzione terminata";

?>
```

If I run robot file manually from shell it works fine:

```
robot -d demo/result demo/demo.robot
```

If I run the robot file from web page, it not works, the page is in a loop state without error. In The geckodriver-1.log there is no error:

```
1574886675597   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/home/user/robot/firefox/firefox" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-pro
file" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileQAxKyX"
```

Where I wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why call `demoSuite.robot` in PHP script`? The filename is `demo.robot` and you can run it successfully using that filename from shell?

Comment: yes run via shell it works fine. the correct file name is demoSuite, it was my mistake to write demo.robot

Comment: Then please make according corrections to the question part.